# System calls with struct parameters (Linux)

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

How is it that certain System calls take pointers to structs as arguments? If these structs are defined in the kernel, then how can user programs create instances of them?

Comment: What system call takes a struct argument?  I can think of several that take *pointers* to structs, but none that take an actual struct.

Comment: Fine then, pointers to structs. It doesn't change my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic here.  The struct types used in syscalls and meant to be user-createable are declared in header files, just as the syscalls themselves are.  Take stat(2):

```
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

You get the declaration of `struct stat` (on Linux) by including `sys/stat.h`.

Some types are not meant to be directly declared by client code, however.  In comments you mentioned semaphores, and `sem_t` is an example of such.  The user header provides only an incomplete declaration, so you can't create an instance directly.  This is intentional.  In those cases there will be a call that creates an instance and returns a pointer to it, for example:

```
   sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag);
```

You are expected to provide that same pointer as an argument to subsequent syscalls, even though you can't dereference it yourself (because its declaration is incomplete).  The distinction between structs and struct pointers is extremely important here.

Comment: And the man page for the syscall will tell you exactly which headers you should include, in which relative order.

Comment: I see. So is it a redefinition of a stat struct inside the kernel? If so, is it possible to this with more complicated structs like semaphores which use other structs defined in the kernel?

Comment: I don't understand your fixation on "inside the kernel".  `struct stat` is a data type used by the kernel, yes.  A declaration of it is provided in a header file so that users can interpret values of that type and declare instances of their own.  The complexity of the type is not really relevant.

Comment: Edited to describe the use of opaque pointers, as are involved in some syscalls.

Answer (score 0):

Every time , when you create a new structure inside the kernel , it can be exported to userspace by executing "make headers_install".

So if the user space binary is built in the same machine , it would be having identical copy of the header files(typically in /usr/include).Hence system calls can specify pointers to structures as parameters.